# Refresh button using streamlit. Had to click on refresh twice to make it work

Tags: python, streamlit

How to make it work on single click.

```
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Function to read DataFrame from CSV
def read_dataframe():

    return pd.read_excel(r"E:\projects\smartscan2_1\patients_info.xlsx")

def main():
    st.title("Refresh DataFrame Example")

    # Generate or retrieve the DataFrame
    if 'data' not in st.session_state:
        st.session_state.data = read_dataframe()

    # Display the DataFrame
    st.dataframe(st.session_state.data)

    # Add a refresh button
    if st.button("Refresh"):
        # Read the DataFrame from CSV and store it in session_state
        st.session_state.data = read_dataframe()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: looks like you have to st.rerun() somewhere in your code

Comment: where to put it ?

Comment: I put it below `st.session_state.data = read_dataframe()` . The app continuously runs in infinite loop and doesn't stop.

Answer (score 0):

You can use callback function on the refresh button.

I would suggest to cache the dataframe to show it quickly, especially for big excel file.

Here is the updated code.

```py
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd


@st.cache_data
def read_dataframe():
    """Read excel file and return as pandas dataframe."""
    return pd.read_excel(r"E:\projects\smartscan2_1\patients_info.xlsx")


def button_cb():
    """Clears cached data if Refresh button is clicked."""
    read_dataframe.clear()


def main():
    st.title("Refresh DataFrame Example")

    # Display the DataFrame
    st.dataframe(read_dataframe())

    # Add a refresh button
    st.button("Refresh", on_click=button_cb)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Ref:
https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/performance/st.cache_data